# Maintaining Excel precision while performing computations in Java

Tags: java, excel, floating-point-precision

How can you maintain Excel level precision while performing computations in Java. In most cases using BigDecimal would solve the issue but what about when using BigDecimals in complex calculations.

For example, the formula for present value being:

PV = P / (1 + r)^n

now if each of these components are BigDecimal values, BigDecimal does not provide a mechanism to raise a BigDecimal to a fraction power.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation of common mathematical functions for BigDecimal http://arxiv.org/abs/0908.3030v2.

It contains implementation of pow which supports what you need.